# Twitter-like avatar/username link highlighting

Tags: html, css, click

On Twitter website a tweet contains, among other things, a 48px square avatar, a display name (like Fred Q. Fish) and an account name (like @fredfish).

These three things are "grouped" so that a mouseover of any of them causes a hover effect. The only visual feedback of the hover is that the display name changes color and gains an underline.

The entire "group" is also a link in that *any* of them can be clicked.

I've been trying to duplicate this behavior using only HTML5 and CSS without success. (No javascript.) Any ideas?

(edit) My attempt. This does everything I want except the username gets underlined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.group {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#009;
}
.group:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#090;
}
.avatar {
    float:left;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.fullname {
}
.username {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
}
</style>
<a class="group" href="#"><img class="avatar" src="sample.jpg" alt="">
    <strong class="fullname">Fred Q. Fish</strong>
    <span class="username">@fredfish</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Edited post to show my example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? Changed your `.group:hover`.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj1kfmpm/)

```
.group:hover .fullname {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#090;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! I did not understand that CSS classes could be stacked that way.